# Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning Error while executing login route

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone explain me the error and give me the solution?

Code is

```
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.body.email || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(401).json({ success:false, message:'Email or Password Missing' });
  }

  let fetchedUser;

  const isEmailValid = emailPatternMatch(req.body.email);
  if(!isEmailValid){
    return res.status(401).json({ success:false, message:'Email not valid' });
  }

  User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    .then(user => {
      if (!user){
        return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message:'Email Address is not Registered' });
      }

      fetchedUser = user;
      return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    })
    .then(result=> {
      if(!result){
        return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message:'Incorrect Password' });
      }
      const token = jwt.sign({ email: fetchedUser.email, userId: fetchedUser._id }, scretKey, { expiresIn: "1h" } );
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, token: token, userId: fetchedUser._id, expiresIn: 3600 });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(401).json({ success:false, message: 'Authentication Failed' });
    });
});
```

Error is

> (node:4084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
>   [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the
>   client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\umesh\Desktop\Locationist\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\umesh\Desktop\Locationist\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\umesh\Desktop\Locationist\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
>       at C:\Users\umesh\Desktop\Locationist\backend\routes\user.js:82:30
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) (node:4084)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which  was not
>   handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
>   promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
>   (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
>   (rejection id: 1) (node:4084) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
>   that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
>   non-zero exit code.

Comment: Does this happen in any specific instance? E.g. only when you type in the wrong password or the right password or when the email does not exist in the DB?

Comment: Your code is somehow calling `res.status().json()` more than once, which throws an error because a server can't respond to a single browser request more than once. Use console.log(1), 2, 3, 4, to see how far it gets and when it goes bad. You can wrap everything inside your route with a try{}catch{} if you don't really care, or you can refactor your function to use async/await, which will benefit you because you'll be able to predictably return a single response.

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing that in your first `then` you are calling `res.status` if the user is not found. In your next `then`, you will potentially be calling `res.status` again, which would result in the promise being rejected, since it was already called. In your `catch` you are again calling `res.status`, thus rejecting that promise which has no catch around it, leading to an unhandled promise.

To fix this you will need to avoid calling `res.status` multiple times. Your could e.g. throw an exception in your `then` and let your `catch` handle it:

```
...
User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    .then(user => {
      if (!user){
        throw { success: false, message:'Email Address is not Registered' };
      }

      fetchedUser = user;
      return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    })
    .then(result=> {
      if(!result){
        throw { success: false, message:'Incorrect Password' };
      }
      const token = jwt.sign({ email: fetchedUser.email, userId: fetchedUser._id }, scretKey, { expiresIn: "1h" } );
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, token: token, userId: fetchedUser._id, expiresIn: 3600 });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(401).json(err);
    });
```

Comment: when I return some thing from first `then` block will it still go to next `then` block ?

Comment: Yes. You are (in the intended path) returning `bcrypt.compare` and expecting the result in the next `then` as well. If a promise is returned in a `then` (like with `bcrypt.compare`) the result of that promise is passed to the next `then`. If a non-promise is returned (or nothing at all is returned) in a `then`, the returned value (or undefined) is passed to the next `then`.